# Find all players with the longest winning streak

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to crack the problem of finding the player(s) with the longest streak of winning using Python's `3.2.` I am only able to work out an unscalable solution, but I could not come up with a better one yet. Can anyone please help me with a better solution? Also, I am curious how to adapt such solution to output the player(s) with the longest winning streak per month or year?

Below is the sample dataframe `players_results`

```
Player_id     Match_Date             Match_Result
401           2021-05-04 00:00:00    W
401           2021-05-09 00:00:00    L
401           2021-05-16 00:00:00    W
401           2021-05-18 00:00:00    W
401           2021-05-22 00:00:00    L
401           2021-06-15 00:00:00    L
401           2021-06-16 00:00:00    W
401           2021-06-18 00:00:00    W
402           2021-05-14 00:00:00    L
402           2021-05-23 00:00:00    L
402           2021-05-24 00:00:00    W
402           2021-06-01 00:00:00    W
402           2021-06-02 00:00:00    W
402           2021-07-01 00:00:00    W
403           2021-05-03 00:00:00    L
403           2021-05-11 00:00:00    W
403           2021-05-12 00:00:00    W
403           2021-05-13 00:00:00    W
403           2021-05-20 00:00:00    W
403           2021-05-25 00:00:00    W
403           2021-07-06 00:00:00    L
404           2021-05-10 00:00:00    W
404           2021-05-16 00:00:00    W
404           2021-05-20 00:00:00    W
404           2021-05-22 00:00:00    W
404           2021-05-28 00:00:00    L
405           2021-05-07 00:00:00    L
405           2021-05-25 00:00:00    W
405           2021-06-06 00:00:00    L
405           2021-06-07 00:00:00    W
405           2021-06-14 00:00:00    W
405           2021-07-01 00:00:00    W
```

**Expected Output**

```
player_id     longest_winningstreak
403           5
```

My **unscalable** code

```
df = players_results.groupby('player_id').count()
df = df['match_date'].reset_index()
#record result of player_id = 401 into vector b
a = [] # record the number of consecutive "W" of player_id = 401
x = 0
for i in range(df['match_date'][0]):
    if players_results['match_result'][i] == 'W':
        x = x + 1
        if (i == df['match_date'][0]-1):
            a.append(x)
    else:
        a.append(x)
        x = 0
print(a)
b = []
b.append([df['player_id'][0],max(a)])
print(b)

c = []
y=0
for i in range(df['match_date'][0], df['match_date'][0]+df['match_date'][1]):
    if players_results['match_result'][i] == 'W':
        y = y + 1
        if (i == df['match_date'][0]+df['match_date'][1]-1):
            c.append(y)
    else:
        c.append(y)
        y = 0
#record result of player_id = 402 into the vector b
b.append([df['player_id'][1],max(c)])

d = []
z=0
for i in range(df['match_date'][0]+df['match_date'][1], df['match_date'] [0]+df['match_date'][1]+df['match_date'][2]):
    if players_results['match_result'][i] == 'W':
        z = z + 1
        if (i == df['match_date'][0]+df['match_date'][1]+df['match_date'][2]-1):
            d.append(z)
    else:
        d.append(z)
        z = 0
b.append([df['player_id'][2],max(d)])

e = []
z2=0
for i in range(df['match_date'][0]+df['match_date'][1]+df['match_date'][2], df['match_date'][0]+df['match_date'][1]+df['match_date'][2]+df['match_date'][3]):
    if players_results['match_result'][i] == 'W':
        z2 = z2 + 1
        if (i == df['match_date'][0]+df['match_date'][1]+df['match_date'][2]+df['match_date'][3]-1):
            e.append(z2)
    else:
        e.append(z2)
        z2 = 0
#print(e)
b.append([df['player_id'][3],max(e)])

f = []
z3=0
for i in range(df['match_date'][0]+df['match_date'][1]+df['match_date'][2]+df['match_date'][3], df['match_date'][0]+df['match_date'][1]+df['match_date'][2]+df['match_date'][3]+df['match_date'][4]):
    if players_results['match_result'][i] == 'W':
        z3 = z3 + 1
        if (i == df['match_date'][0]+df['match_date'][1]+df['match_date'][2]+df['match_date'][3]+df['match_date'][4]-1):
            f.append(z3)
    else:
        f.append(z3)
        z3 = 0
#print(e)
b.append([df['player_id'][4],max(f)])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter groups crated by cumulative sums with compare not equal `W` with [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) and then get max value with `player_id` by [`Series.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.agg.html) with [`Series.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) and `max`:

```
m = df['Match_Result'].str.upper().ne('W')

s = m.cumsum()[~m].groupby(df['Player_id']).value_counts().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)

df = s.agg({'player_id': 'idxmax', 'longest_winningstreak':'max'}).to_frame(0).T
print (df)
   player_id  longest_winningstreak
0        403                      5
```

Solution per months:

```
df['Match_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Match_Date'])

m = df['Match_Result'].ne('W')

s = (m.cumsum()[~m].groupby([df['Player_id'], df['Match_Date'].dt.to_period('m')])
       .value_counts()
       .reset_index(level=-1, drop=True))

df1 = (s.groupby(level=0)
        .agg([('period',lambda x: x.idxmax()[1]),('longest_winningstreak','max')]))

print (df1)
            period  longest_winningstreak
Player_id                                
401        2021-06                      2
402        2021-06                      2
403        2021-05                      5
404        2021-05                      4
405        2021-06                      2
```

Answer (score 1):

One way using `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

s = df["Match_Result"].str.lower().eq("w")

def longest_pattern(ser):
    lens = [len(list(g)) for k, g in groupby(ser) if k]
    return max(lens)

new_df = s.groupby(df["Player_id"]).apply(longest_pattern)
```

Or bit of a trick, but another way using `re.findall`:

```
import re

def longest(string):
    return max(len(i) for i in re.findall("w+", string, flags=re.I))

new_df = df.groupby("Player_id")["Match_Result"].sum().apply(longest)
```

You can then use `pandas.Series.nlargest` to get the desired output:

```
new_df.nlargest(1)
```

Output:

```
Player_id
403    5
Name: Match_Result, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, Chris! A quick question: your `df` is the original dataframe `players_results`, correct? Also, sorry for my typos, but all the entries under the column `Match_Result` should be either `W` or `L`, so I think the second row of your code needs to be `s = df["Match_Result"].str.upper().eq("W")`?

Comment: Your first code works!! The only minor thing is that the output was not in the dataframe. Do we have any shortcuts for that or we have to create one by ourselves?